# Would need to redirect with .htaccess from folder to file

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do a particular redirect

/mytag

redirect to file.php

the thing is it can be either /mytag/ or /mytag only without the final slash.

can't find this.. thanks

tried with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^mytag(.*)$ file.php
```

Comment: Do you mean a directory index?https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: I'd actually mean just the string, say if I needed a hack for the directory to actually exist and there's a solution I'd go for it, to me if /mytag to file.php works to be able to use it in a link is great

Comment: You might look at the WordPress `.htaccess` which routes all requests (however many slashes) through `index.php` http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't have a file or directory called "mytag", then you can just end the regex with `/?` to make the ending slash optional:

```
RewriteRule ^mytag/?$ file.php [L]
```

Though what you already have should allow both the slash or no slash at the end. This won't work if you have a directory called mytag because mod_dir and `DirectorySlash` will always redirect a request for a directory that doesn't have a trailing slash to the same request *with* the trailing slash. If you have `Multiviews` turned on, and you happen to have a `mytag.php` (or something similar), mod_negotiation will kick in and the rewrite rule will get ignored.

Comment: I don't have the directory mytag or the file mytag, it gives me a 404, this is the only rewrite rule I'm using with this server, could there be something turned off that needs to be turned on

Comment: it actually is working on its own with this server, but not cause of the line